# Add custom file (.bin) to Unity Android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project i have placed a `.bin` file at the project root folder, through a script i i am calling a `dll` function that uses this file and it works for `PC` builds.
Now i am compiling for `Android` and the `.dll` file was replaced with `.so`, and i got a bit confused with where do i need to place the file in order for the `Android` system will find it?

Comment: Why you doesn't place .bin file in Resources folder?

Comment: tried to... it didnt do the job

Comment: What exactly was the .dll function you have called?

Comment: Resources os Assets can work, but you have to change the accessing code to read these Android APIs, or else copy from them to an actual filesystem file and point the accessing code at the location of that.